# Angular How to Delete a component instances using its object reference

Tags: angular, dynamic, components

CLI 6.2.1 Angular 6.1.7 - I dynamically create components as the user requests them.  The HTML displays each instance as built and they are correct and unique.

At some point, I need to delete one (or more) of them.  By that I mean, I not only don't need the DOM representation, I don't need that specific instance or object reference at all.

New Information:  Here is how the component is created:

```
    createComponent(componentType): any {

    const factory: ComponentFactory<any> = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(componentType);
    this.componentRef = this.container.createComponent(factory);
    return this.componentRef;  // return the REFERENCE containing the instance.
  }
```

I have tried:

```
Items.objRef.delete;
Items.objRef.delete();
Items.objRef.instance.delete;
Items.objRef.instance.delete();
```

After this, I would expect to:

```
Items.objRef = null;  // just to clean up
```

and create a new one later if needed.

Do I need to force Angular to "detectChanges()"?

Any other ideas?
Thanks in advance,
Chuck aka Yogi.

Comment: If the component is not in view, it should not have any object or DOM representation. How are you setting the reference for the object ?

Comment: Regarding the reference: see the updates I added to the description above.